# Retrieving attachment table previously created during geoprocessing and renaming attachments using ModelBuilder, ArcPy and ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, attachments

I've created a model in ModelBuilder (ArcGIS Pro 2.7.2) and I'm trying to retrieve an attachment table created previously in the model using feature class to feature class. I'd then like to run the following python script to rename attachments in the table

```
fields = ['REL_GLOBALID', 'ATT_NAME']
featureClass = 'DFE__ATTACH'
update_dictionary = {}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass, fields) as updates:
    for row in updates:
        if row[0] not in update_dictionary.keys():
            update_dictionary[row[0]] = 1
        else:
            update_dictionary[row[0]] += 1
        row[1] = 'Photo ' + str(update_dictionary[row[0]]) + '.jpg'
        updates.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Is your model working as expected?  If so, and if you're stuck on your script, what happens when you run the code that you've presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run small amounts of python code as part of a workflow WITHIN an existing model you would typically use the model only [Calculate Value tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm).